# How to make json schema take in any number of parent-key values regardless of name, and evaluate children?

Tags: json, schema

I have a json and schema like the following:

```
**JSON**
    {
      "randKey1" : {"message":"string","color":"string"},
      "randKey2" : {"message":"string","color":"string"}
    }
    
**SCHEMA**
    {
      "properties": {
                      ???: {
                             "type":"object",
                             "properties": {
                                             "message":{"type":"string"}
                                             "color":{"type":"string"}
                                           }
                           }
                    }
    }
```

The ??? being the unknown parent names.  How can I make the schema evaluate each parent in the json?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to use the `patternProperties` keyword.

For example, if all your JSON is of the form:

```
{
    KEY_thing1 : {object},
    KEY_thing2 : {object}
}
```

You could use a schema like:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^KEY_": {
            "type": "object",
            ...
}
```

To evaluate each object starting with `KEY_`